# Can't run two functions

Tags: javascript, html, math, calculator

When I try to click the button "calculate" it only works from entering number to square root, but on the other hand, when I try to put a number in my box2, it won't show anything in box1. Should I add another function which includes ConvertToSqrt() and ConvertToNum()?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function ConvertToSqrt()
 {
   var num, sqrt;
   num = parseFloat(document.getElementById('box1').value);
   var sqrt = NumberToSquare(num);
   box2.value=sqrt;
 }

 function ConvertToNum()
 {
   var sqrt, num;
   sqrt = parseFloat(document.getElementById('box2').value);
   num = SquareToNum(sqrt);
   box1.value=num;
 }

 function NumberToSquare(num)
 {
   var sqrt; 
   sqrt = Math.sqrt(num); 
   return sqrt; 
 } 

 function SquareToNumber(sqrt)
 { 
   var num; 
   num = Math.pow(sqrt,2);
   return num; 
 } 
  </script>
```

```
  <body>
  <div style="border: solid; width: 300px; background-color: #83CAFF">

  <table>
  <th></th> <th>Calculater</th>
  <tr>
  <th>Enter Number:</th><th><input type="text" id="box1"></th>
  <tr>
  <th>SquareRoot:</th><th><input type="text" id="box2"></th>
  <tr>
  <th></th><th><input type="button" value="Calculate"
  onclick="ConvertToNum(); ConvertToSqrt();">
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: May I suggest reading about [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)?

Comment: Check the console for errors. Trace through your code using the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I would do it. If you are willing to use jquery its pretty easy.**

***UPDATE: CHANGED TO PLAIN JS***

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");

resetButton.onclick = function(){
  box1.value = "";
  box2.value = "";
};

//---------------------------------------------

box1.onkeyup = function(){
  box2.value = ConvertToSqrt(box1.value);
};

function ConvertToSqrt(num)
 {   
   var sqrt = NumberToSquare(num);   
   return sqrt;
 }

function NumberToSquare(num)
 {
   var sqrt = Math.sqrt(num); 
   return sqrt; 
 } 

//---------------------------------------------

box2.onkeyup = function(){
  box1.value = ConvertToNum(box2.value);
};

 function ConvertToNum(sqrt)
 {
   var num = SquareToNumber(sqrt);
   return num;
 }

 function SquareToNumber(sqrt)
 {  
   var num = Math.pow(sqrt,2);
   return num; 
 }
```

```html
<div style="border: solid; width: 300px; background-color: #83CAFF">

  <table>
  <th></th> <th>Calculater</th>
  <tr>
  <th>Enter Number:</th><th><input type="text" id="box1"></th>
  <tr>
  <th>SquareRoot:</th><th><input type="text" id="box2"></th>
  <tr>
  <th></th><th><input id="reset" type="button" value="reset">
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

you missspelt SquareToNumber function below. Was SquareToNum.

```
function ConvertToNum() {
  var sqrt, num;
  sqrt = parseFloat(document.getElementById('box2').value);
  num = SquareToNumber(sqrt);
  //num = SquareToNum(sqrt);
  box1.value = num;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use jequry. Is there a way to do the HTML and JavaScript way?

Answer (score 0):

yes,you should add another function which includes ConvertToSqrt() and ConvertToNum() ,and you shouldn't bind event in the html because it is unmaintainable , just use addEventListener or others to do it in JavaScript